# InfoBox padding-left

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3, dom

I am creating a map using Google Maps API3 and the InfoBox extension: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html

I am able to add overall padding to the Infobox like:

```js
var infoOptions = {
disableAutoPan: true,
closeBoxURL: "",
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(20, 0),
boxStyle: { background: "#ffffff", padding:"4px" }
};
```

but when I try changing that to be just left padding it causes the map to not display:

```
var infoOptions = {
disableAutoPan: true,
closeBoxURL: "",
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(20, 0),
boxStyle: { background: "#ffffff", padding-left:"4px" }
};
```

The only change I make between the two is adding '-left' to the end of the padding styler. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to make it work. The trick is to use HTML DOM properties instead of CSS so in my case it would be:

```
boxStyle: { background: "#ffffff", paddingLeft:"4px" }
```

instead of what I had earlier.